# Remote rsyslog only writing logging data to /var/log/syslog and not custom logfiles

Tags: amazon-ec2, logging, rsyslog

I'm having a problem setting up rsyslog to log remote logging data to a specific file. I have two Windows Server 2008 boxes that each have a C# application using NLog.Targets.Syslog which log their debugging data to a linux box. All the logging data is getting written to /var/log/syslog just fine, but I want to have a seperate logfile for each server and the logging data isn't being written to those custom log files.

Here is my setup:

/etc/rsyslog.conf

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

I made a custom conf file in /etc/rsyslog.d

/etc/rsyslog.d/22-remote.conf

```
:msg, contains, "AMAZONA-COMPUTERNAME1" /var/log/dbm/server-1.log
& ~
:msg, contains, "AMAZONA-COMPUTERNAME2" /var/log/dbm/server2.log
& ~

*.* /var/log/syslog.log
```

AMAZONA-COMPUTERNAME1 is the windows computer name of the server. I've also tried IP addresses too and that doesn't work either. What am I missing? the logfiles exist in the path /var/log/dbm/

I'm not getting any errors from rsyslog about this and it happily writes all the remote logging data to /var/log/syslog what am I doing wrong?

On the logging server, I'm running ubuntu on an Amazon EC2 instance.

Here is my NLog config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.Syslog" />
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target name="syslog" type="Syslog" syslogserver="server ip here" port="514" facility="Local7"/>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" appendTo="syslog"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Sample log output in /var/log/syslog

```
Oct 15 18:18:50 AMAZONA-COMPUTERNAME2 NLog: 2012-10-15 18:18:50.2890|DEBUG|myapp.download.excel.ExcelWorkbook|  -- Copied in the data table: 0
Oct 15 18:18:50 AMAZONA-COMPUTERNAME2 NLog: 2012-10-15 18:18:50.2890|DEBUG|myapp.download.excel.ExcelWorkbook|  -- Formatted Header and Footer: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, solved it. I changed the config entry in my custom 22-remote.conf file in /etc/rsyslog.d/ from this:

```
:msg, contains, "AMAZONA-COMPUTERNAME1" /var/log/dbm/server-1.log
& ~
:msg, contains, "AMAZONA-COMPUTERNAME2" /var/log/dbm/server2.log
& ~
```

To this:

```
if $fromhost-ip == '10.11.12.12' then /var/log/dbm/server-1.log
& ~
if $fromhost-ip == '10.11.13.13' then /var/log/dbm/server2.log
& ~
```

Comment: I thought the correct operator was isequal instead of == which is why I couldn't get it to work before.

Comment: Really? I use `:fromhost-ip,isequal,"10.x.x.x" -?Template` Where "Template" was previously defined.

Comment: I'm using rsyslog on ubuntu, maybe there's some quirky differences between linux distros?

Comment: I realize the difference now, (I think.) `:fromhost-ip` vs. `if $fromhost-ip`.